# Why react highlight my second <select> option while the specified value is empty?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 `<select>` as in the following code:

```js
function FirstSelect(props) {
  const list = props.list.map(item => {
    return <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.text}</option>
  })
  return <select size='8' onChange={props.onChange}>{list}</select>
}

function SecondSelect(props) {
  console.log(props.value)
  const list = props.list.map(item => {
    return <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.text}</option>
  })
  return <select size='8' onChange={props.onChange} value={props.value}>{list}</select>
}

class TwoSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      firstList: [
        {id: 'fitem1', text: 'fvalue1'},
        {id: 'fitem2', text: 'fvalue2'}
      ],
      secondList: [
        {id: 'sitem1', text: 'svalue1'},
        {id: 'sitem2', text: 'svalue2'}
      ],
      selectedValue1: '',
      selectedValue2: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <FirstSelect list={this.state.firstList} onChange={(e)=>{this.firstListSelectionChanged(e.target.value)}} />
      <div>selectedValue1: {this.state.selectedValue1}</div>
      <SecondSelect list={this.state.secondList} value={this.state.selectedValue2} onChange={(e)=>{this.secondListSelectionChanged(e.target.value)}} />
      <div>selectedValue2: {this.state.selectedValue2}</div>
    </div>
  }

  firstListSelectionChanged(value) {
    this.setState({
      selectedValue1: value
    })
  }

  secondListSelectionChanged(value) {
    this.setState({
      selectedValue2: value
    })
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TwoSelect />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

When it is first rendered, nothing is strange. But when I select an item in the first `<select>`, React highlights the first item in the second `<select>`, the `onChange` event is not fired, and `selectedValue2` is still an empty string. Hence, clicking on first item of the second `<select>` does not fired its `onChange` event. (click the second item, then click the first item works normally)

What I expected is the second `<select>` will not be highlighted any item when its attribute value is empty!

I tried to use

```
this.state = {
  selectedValue1: null,
  selectedValue2: null
}
```

and it works like i expected, but React keeps recommending to use empty string instead of `null`!

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Where does React recommend using an empty string instead of null?

Comment: @Scimonster In the console when you run it, it suggests either empty string or undefined, where undefined seems to be the better option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that it shouldn't be null, but as React suggest, it should be either undefined or an empty string.

The reason `null` is not an accepted value is because attributes only allow string values, and no object. As null is an object, it is not recommended to use it. Undefined however will not add the attribute (as it is not defined).

The reason why this is so can be found in the [sourcecode](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/fiber/wrappers/ReactDOMFiberSelect.js). When a select is not a multi value, the first option gets [selected](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/fiber/wrappers/ReactDOMFiberSelect.js#L107) by default when the value is not undefined. When a value is given, it must be stringable, as you can find in the comment section of the code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/fiber/wrappers/ReactDOMFiberSelect.js#L107)

When the value is set to undefined, react doesn't complain, as you can see in this snippet

```js
class CustomList extends React.Component {
 render() {
    var selectedId = this.props.selectedValue;
   return (
     <select size="8" onChange={this.props.onChange} value={selectedId}>
       { this.props.items.map( item => <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.text}</option> ) }
      </select>
    );
  }
}

class TwoSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      firstList: [
        {id: 'fitem1', text: 'fvalue1'},
        {id: 'fitem2', text: 'fvalue2'}
      ],
      secondList: [
        {id: 'sitem1', text: 'svalue1'},
        {id: 'sitem2', text: 'svalue2'}
      ],
      selectedValue1: undefined,
      selectedValue2: undefined
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <CustomList placeholder="select" items={this.state.firstList} selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue1} onChange={(e)=>{this.selectionChanged('selectedValue1', e.target.value)}} />
      <div>selectedValue1: {this.state.selectedValue1}</div>
      <CustomList placeholder="" items={this.state.secondList} selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue2} onChange={(e)=>{this.selectionChanged('selectedValue2', e.target.value)}} />
      <div>selectedValue2: {this.state.selectedValue2}</div>
    </div>
  }

  selectionChanged(stateKey, value) {
    this.setState({
      [stateKey]: value
    });
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <TwoSelect />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

For some extra recommendations, there is no reason why you would make multiple list components that do the exact same thing. That would make your application hugely complex in the future, where you really don't need this complexity.

Just try to see what can be reused in your code, and then use only those single components.

For example, your `FirstList` and `SecondList` component can be simplified to for example `CustomList` and then you only need to call `CustomList` twice in your `TwoSelect` render method.

```
class CustomList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var selectedId = this.props.selectedValue;
    return (
      <select onChange={this.props.onChange} value={selectedId}>
        { this.props.items.map( item => <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.text}</option> ) }
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

When creating `select` boxes, mostly a default value is selected, to circumvent this, you can choose to add an extra empty option, this one would be preselected in this case.

If I would now render your `TwoSelect` component, I can change the following things to make your application a bit easier to maintain in the future (say a third list would be added later ;-))

```
  render() {
    return <div>
      <CustomList 
        placeholder="select" 
        items={this.state.firstList} 
        selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue1}
        onChange={(e)=>{this.selectionChanged('selectedValue1', e.target.value)}} />
      <div>selectedValue1: {this.state.selectedValue1}</div>
      <CustomList 
        placeholder="" 
        items={this.state.secondList} 
        selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue2} 
        onChange={(e)=>{this.selectionChanged('selectedValue2', e.target.value)}} />
      <div>selectedValue2: {this.state.selectedValue2}</div>
    </div>;
  }
```

As you can see, I removed the need for the 2 handlers, now your selection changed event rather looks like this:

```
selectionChanged(stateKey, value) {
  this.setState({
    [stateKey]: value
  })
}
```

This would expect stateKey to be a string value, like `'selectedValue1'` as you can see from the change in the handlers above

A demo using jsfiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/dxxxa3eh/4/)

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question in the title. *Why* do `undefined`, `null`, and the empty string cause it to work the way it does? And why does it only get messed up on the second render? (Also, there may be a reason why the OP has two separate components. The actual application may be more complex, and this is just an MCVE.)

Comment: @Scimonster Point taken, I added the reason why `null` cannot be used for an attribute value. The other extra points are just recommendations, although you might be correct that this is just an MCVE, I thought it could be helpful to point out other ways of working with events and common components

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. I pass objects all the time. React props can be of any type.

Comment: @Scimonster Yeah, react props as you say can be of any value, once they are given to html elements however they get transformed as attributes, and those are only allowed to be stringable values

Comment: But `<select value>` isn't a standard HTML attribute. It's a React prop that it then uses to set the selected option.

Comment: @Scimonster Actually, from the [sourcecode](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/fiber/wrappers/ReactDOMFiberSelect.js), you can see that when it's not multiple selection, the prop has to be stringable and this is marked [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/fiber/wrappers/ReactDOMFiberSelect.js#L107). When no value was found in the selected options (as null is not undefined) the first value gets checked which you can see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/fiber/wrappers/ReactDOMFiberSelect.js#L100)

Comment: That is exactly what you should put in the answer.

Comment: @Scimonster By all means, I updated the answer with the links to the sourcecode ;)

Comment: Now it seems to fully answer the question. +1 :)

Comment: I focused on the problem when minimizing it to an MCVE from my app! But your recommendations are great. React says: "_Consider using the empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components_". At first I avoided `undefined` because I want the second `select` to be controlled. But in the end, it is what I must use (I spent my last hour to search and re-read about controlled vs uncontrolled components and find out that I misunderstood them). What is still in question is what does "_Consider using the empty string to clear the component_" means? It is still confused!